# Can not add values from forms to Django models

Tags: django, database, forms, model

**I made a form and there I had a multiple-choice field called artists which I got from my database and while adding a song a user can select multiple artists and save the song.**

The artists are a ManyToManyField in Django models.

**models.py**

```
class Artists(models.Model):
    """ Fields for storing Artists Data """
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)
    dob = models.DateField()
    bio = models.TextField(max_length = 150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist_name

class Songs(models.Model):
    """ Fields for storing song data """
    song_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = False)        
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = False)
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artists)
    release_date = models.DateField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class Song_input(forms.Form):
    queryset = Artists.objects.only('artist_name')
    OPTIONS = []
    for i in queryset:
        s = []
        s = [i, i]
        OPTIONS.append(s)

    artist_name = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,choices=OPTIONS)
    song_name = forms.CharField()       
    genre = forms.CharField()
    release_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput)
```

Now I want to get all the values selected from the form and save to my database. Here the artist_name may have multiple values.

I have tried using the add() and create() methods but can not figure out how to add all the data where one field (artist_name) having multiple data to my database.

Comment: Pleae make use of a `ModelForm`.

Comment: thank you I now used it but can I use my custom widgets with ModelForm?

Comment: yes, as specified in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60916341/67579), you can specify the `widgets` in the `Meta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly advise to make use of a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/). Especially since you make use of `ManyToManyField`s, which are more cumbersome to save yourself.

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms

class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Songs
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'artist': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            'release_date': forms.DateInput
        }
```

There is thus no need to specify the fields yourself, you can change the widgets by adding these to the [**`widgets`** dictionary [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) of the `Meta` subclass.

In your view, you can then both render and sae objects with that form:

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import SongForm

def add_song(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SongForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = SongForm()
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'form': form})
```

The `form.save()` will save the object in the database.

In the template, you can then render the template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'name-of-add_song-view' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @SubhamBanerjee: ah, but that is because the field is named `artist`, not `artist_name`.

Comment: yes the artist worked but I want the date field as calender

I also tried 

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
 input_type = 'date'

Comment: @SubhamBanerjee: did you replace `'release_date': forms.DateInput` with `'release_date': DateInput`?

Comment: @SubhamBanerjee: but then you are still referring to the *old* `form.DateInput`. If you subclass, you should of course refer to the new class.

Comment: `class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
 input_type = 'date'

class SongInput(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:

  model = Songs
  fields = '__all__'
  widgets = {
            'artist': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            'release_data': DateInput()
        }
`
look I have this in my forms.py but not working in date field

Comment: @SubhamBanerjee: aargghh... I made a typo (that was copied), it is `release_date`, not `release_data`.